# How much vocabulary should be studied a day?

Tags: learning

And not only vocabulary. What is the amount of daily  study material for  an advanced learner of English?

Comment: This question does not seem to be about English in particular - it could be applied to any material appropriate to be studied. And any serious pedagogical answer would need to take into account a certain amount of personal data and aptitudes of the one asking the question.

Comment: It could be applied, but I am not asking about 'any material', as you say. I am asking about English.

Comment: As much as you can reasonably handle in the long term.  It's more important that you study consistently every day, so don't study so much that you burn out, but push yourself so you keep making progress. Ideally, learn as much vocabulary as you can in context; learning a smaller amount in context is better than cramming a ton of vocab out of context.

Comment: How much time have you got? How much English, of what kind, do you want to learn? What are you going to **do** with it? What's your native tongue? What and how many other languages are you acquainted with?

Comment: I study ten words every day. Expressions and useful phrases,  idioms. Expressions from movies and papers from any possible source.  I was just wondering if 10 words plus one idiom and a few phrases is enough.

Comment: I have 5-6 hours every day.  I will be studying at an English- speaking university next year. My naitive tongue is Russian. I am acquainted with French and German.

Comment: I agree with Stoney's questions. Ultimately, the only correct answer to this question is: "It depends."

Comment: What's wrong with answers that are based  on opinions? That's exactly what I needed. And I got it. Thanks.

Comment: @Monica There's nothing intrinsically wrong with opinion-based answers.  In fact, [some subjective questions are good](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).  But for this question, the answer differs quite a bit from student to student, and it even varies for the same student over time, so it's very difficult to write a meaningful answer.  I think that this is a question you must answer for yourself based on your own experiences.  (I've already given my opinion, which you can see in the third comment above.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, as much as you can handle but always in **relation to something you read or study**. However, the most important is to use that vocabulary in writing or speaking.